# How to make Clear button work in MUI Date Picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a MUI `TextField` `type='date'` (Date Picker) in React project. The Clear button is not working. Ideally it should clear the date values and reset it to empty.

[image]

```
<TextField
  variant="outlined"                                                                              
  placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
  type="date"                                                                                 
  required
  sx={{
    svg: { color: '#fff' },
    input: { color: '#fff' },
  }}
  value={training.start_date.split('T')[0]}
  onChange={(e) => onChange(index, i, 'start_date', 
  e.target.value)}
  InputLabelProps={{
  shrink: true,
  }} />
```

Any idea how can I fix this.

Comment: Can you share more code about how the states are defined and the JSX for the clear and today buttons?

Comment: @HittuDesai the clear and today buttons are MUI TextField's built in buttons. I wonder how can I explicitly control them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to delete the `required` prop from your `TextField` component to be able to use `clear` button. Also **clear** and **today** buttons are native buttons of input with `type="date"`, not the MUI TextField's.

Comment: Amazing! Got it. Is there a way to hide the Clear button if the Date field is required cause it makes no sense to have it there.

Comment: The whole pop-up calendar with buttons is browser specific element. As per google chrome documentation, it's not possible to disable or hide buttons for now- https://developer.chrome.com/blog/quick-faqs-on-input-type-date-in-google-chrome/#how-do-i-change-the-appearance-of-the-date-picker

Another option is to try to use a special date picker component where you have control over the elements https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/